# stuck in feeding my SVM after creating my node2vec model

Tags: numpy, networkx, svm, word2vec

I am trying to do node classification using Node2Vec and SVM on a graph obtained from protein-protein interaction to predict disease genes related to a specific disease. to be accurate. the point is that, I have created a Graph using `networkx` , my nodes have `labels`(names of protein) and attributes=0/1(if this protein is causing a disease or not). I applied `node2vec` on this graph and I have my model. (I don't care about values of p and q at this stage) but I don't know how to proceed and feed it to SVM or more importantly, how to reduce dimensions of my vectorized graph before feeding it to SVM. plus, I don't know if in these vectors, the attributes of my node are included or not. separately however, I have a dictionary called lbls to have my nodes and their value
here is small piece of code

```
node2vec = Node2Vec(G, dimensions=512, workers=4,p=1,q=2)
model = node2vec.fit(window=10, min_count=1, batch_words=4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`node2vec` is an unsupervised node embedding method, which is based on `Word2Vec`. Have a look at the [snap documentation](https://snap.stanford.edu/node2vec/) for a brief description of the model. It will not use any of your attributes/features to create the embedding. It uses a shallow encoding, which are directly learned using a random walk based objective function. For details look at the paper or check the [Stanford Lecture](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs224w/index.html) about node embeddings, which covers in detail Node2Vec. Your embedding dimension is currently `512` (for the node embedding of node2vec), which you probably can reduce.

Comment: thank you for your reply, i now have model.wv. can this be seen as my X_train ? and my attributes for each node as Y_train ?

Comment: If your desired task is to classify disease/note disease based on the retrieved node embedding, then your input features (X) is the result of the node2vec (aka .wv) and your desired output (Y) are your attributes. So yes, but probably you want to split them into some way, e.g. 80/20 train/test or perform cross validation. Please accept, if my answer solved your question.